# Pandas join raises KeyError / merge raises ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I am trying to join two data frames (`df_out` and `j`) using a common column (`tct`).

`df.head()` returns:

```
        tct
0  10000.00
1  10001.00
2  10002.00
3  10003.01
4  10003.02
```

First, I tried:

```
df_out = df_out.join(j, on='tct', how = 'left', lsuffix='_left', rsuffix='_right')
```

And received

```
KeyError: 'tct'
```

when `j.head()` returns:

```
         tct  Unnamed: 0
0  9320207.0           0
1  9320206.0           1
2  9320205.0           2
3  9320204.0           3
4  9320203.0           4
```

Then, I tried:

```
df_out = pd.merge(df_out, j, how='left', on='tct')
```

And received

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

when `j.head()` returns:

```
        tct       tct
0  10001.00  10001.00
1  10002.00  10002.00
2  10003.01  10003.01
3  10003.02  10003.02
4  10170.01  10170.01
```

I am not sure where went wrong. How can I join/merge the two data frames?

Comment: Could you add `df_out.head()` and `j.head()` outputs to the question?

Comment: It would help if you provide a full sample program with baked-in input data so we can play with it.  The problem is probably that your data is broken somehow, but it's hard to tell without being able to replicate it (because you never give us any code or input file we can load).

Comment: Added - it seems I only get KeyErrror for both methods now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where went wrong, but it seems the problem was fixed using the merge function after I forced everything into numeric and changed indentation.